# Настройка Eclipse Juno

Tags: настройка, eclipse, c++

Помогите пожалуйста настроить Eclipse Juno под С++. Полное название:

"Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722"

Установлен MinGW. ОС: Windows7 x64

Прописаны в ОС следующие переменные сред :

```
MinGW = c:\MinGW;
PATH = C:\MinGW\bin;
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы проект скомпилировался?

[image]

Comment: А чтоб не париться установите DEV C++ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно, чтобы у вас были необходимые права на файлы проекта.

Посмотрите что в настройках компиляции С++ верно указан компилятор.

Посмотрите не стоит ли флажок "Build automatically" в Windows->Preferences (убрать если стоит).

При создании проекта выберите  **Executable C/C++ Project** тогда Eclipse будет генерить Make-file самостоятельно.

Comment: это настройки компиляции? верно ли они указаны? 
![alt text][1]


создал проект с Hello world, он не запускается:

![alt text][2]

в настройках вообще вот такое (хотя скрином выше в Settings по другому всё):

![alt text][3]

права на файлы проектов вот такие:

![alt text][4]

вначале делаю Build а потом Run

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/JJ2kp.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/dWSGk.png
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/lRo7B.png
  [4]: http://i.imgur.com/0Xc8d.png

Comment: Посмотрите не стоит ли флажок "Build automatically" в Windows->Preferences . Эклипс говорит что проблема в мэйк файле, как вариант - попробуйте создать Executable C/C++ project он должен генерить мэйки сам. По ссылке http://fatalerror.info/index.php?c=100&o=5736 предлагают выбрать еще и Elf Parser, кстати там достаточно вменяемое описание.

Comment: да там написано "Просто создайте в директории с исходными кодами файл и скопируйте туда текст предоставленый ниже" а а какое у него должно быть имя и расширение и кодировка непонятно.

Comment: Executable C/C++ project компилится?

Comment: Да, а я выбирал  GNU Autotools, там тоже есть проект с Hello world. Теперь вроде все компилится, спасибо большое! (в ответе выделите жирным что нужен именно  Executable C/C++ project тип проекта, я отмечу ответ)

Comment: Исправил).

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому еще пригодится

"[Инструкция по созданию и настройке проекта C/C++ в среде Eclipse](http://zns.susu.ru/IT/tasks/docs/EclipseDocs/EclipseInstruction.htm)"